# Delete a MongoDB subdocument by value

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection containing documents that look like this:

```
{
    "user": "foo",
    "topics": {
        "Topic AB": {
            "score": 20,
            "frequency": 3,
            "last_seen": 40
        },
        "Topic BD": {
            "score": 10,
            "frequency": 2,
            "last_seen": 38
        },
        "Topic TF": {
            "score": 19,
            "frequency": 6,
            "last_seen": 20
        }
    }
}
```

I want to remove subdocuments whose last_seen value is less than 30.

I don't want to use arrays here since I'm using `$inc` to update the subdocuments in conjunction with `upsert` (which doesn't support the `$` notation).

The real question here is how can I delete a key depending on its value. Using `$unset` simply drops a subdocument regardless of what it contains.

Comment: Is `topics` an array?

Comment: ma08 - nope, it's a subdocument, with dynamically created keys that differ between documents in this collection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't think this is possible with your current design. Knowing the name of the key whose `last_seen` value you wish to test, for example `Topic TF`, you can do

```
> db.topics.update({"topics.Topic TF.last_seen" : { "$lt" : 30 }}, 
                   { "$unset" : { "topics.Topic TF" : 1} })
```

However, with an embedded document structure, if you don't know the name of the key that you want to query against then you can't run the query. If the Topic XX keys are only known by what's in the document, you'd have to pull the whole document to find out what keys to test, and at that point you ought to just manipulate the document client-side and then update by `_id`.

The best option is to use arrays. The `$` positional operator works with upserts, it just has a serious gotcha that, in the case of an insert, the `$` will be interpreted as part of the field name instead of as an operator, so I understand your conclusion that it doesn't seem feasible. I'm not quite sure how you are using upsert such that arrays seem like they won't work, though. Could you give more detail there and I'll try to help come up with a reasonable workaround to use arrays and `$` with your use case?

Comment: Thanks for your time answering this. The gotcha you described (also detailed here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#upserts is the reason why this can't be a good solution for this specific problem. I guess I'll go back and rethink my design then.